# Auto Layout Troubles

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uilabel, autolayout

I have watched copious amounts of tutorials. Read everything on here and all the information the internet can provide me.

For some reason, I can not grasp how auto layout works.

Here is a screen I am using. [image: Auto Layout Screens]

As you can see I simply have a picker view at the top. I then have a regular sub view underneath that. With a page control as well as some labels.

Everything but the labels seem to work with auto layout. When I try to give the labels constraints, all they do is move off the screen and I can not find them. I want to makes sure all labels are shown on each screen. I have been at this for hours with no avail.

Are there any recommendations to help me solve my problem. I want to make sure all labels show inside the subview.

**Edit 1:** When I try to put all the labels into their own view and do the constraints, everything is gone.

What's weird too is that the option for horizontal spacing, is greyed out.

Here are some screenshots.

[image: No option for horizontal spacing]
[image: Horizontal spacing not able to be clicked]

**Edit 2:** When I choose 'leading space to superview' , everything goes away.
[image: No luck still.]

**Edit 3:** Thanks to @rdelmar I can now get everything in there, but this occurs and when I try to change this, everything goes back weird. But process has been made.

[image: Finally!]

Comment: Where do you want the labels to be?  To the right?

Comment: @Jeef I want the time labels to be to the left and the others to the right.

Comment: The labels on the left need a horizontal spacing constraint to the left side, and the ones on the right should have ones to the right side. What constraints do you now have that don't work?

Comment: @rdelmar I have edited my post to reflect what happened when I tried.

Comment: You don't want horizontal spacing, you want Leading Space to Superview.

Comment: @rdelmar I edited my post once again, to show what happens when I choose that.

Comment: You may be having trouble because of the size classes. It looks like your constraints are on wR hR. You should leave the setting (at the bottom of the screen) to wAny hAny.

Comment: I changed that, then tried the lead space to superview all over again, and everything just disappears!

Comment: @rdelmar Check out the edit! You helped, but now that happens.

Comment: Are you making the constraints to the ones that say "Label" to the right side of the view (trailing)?

Comment: @rdelmar I am concerned now about the subview overlapping the picker on the 3.5 inch iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What color are the constraints on the labels?  If they are not blue they possibly don't have enough constraints.  In general you need a Width, Height, X, Y for an item to show up correctly.

I'm assuming you want to right justify the labels,  you have the following options:

**Easy Mode**

1. Select all your labels
2. Go to the edit menu and select "Embed in View"
3. Set the View properties so that is has a clear background
4. Apply the following constraints

   - Fixed Width
   - Fixed Height
   - Vertical Spacing
   - Training spacing

What this will do is lock the view (and all the stuff inside it) to the right border and the top of its container.

**Hard Mode**
Set the 4 constraints individually for each label.  This is much more work.

Comment: I followed the instructions to the tee and still didn't work.